# Templated function in untemplated class

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a templated function in a class which is not templated.

```
class TheClass
{
    template<typename T>
    int doSomething(T thing);
}

template<typename T>
int TheClass::doSomething(T thing)
{
    ....
}
```

I don't know why I am getting an error "Member not found" when I declare it outside of the class.

Comment: The only error I get is the missing semicolon after the class. I wouldn't be surprised at all if that's a typo and I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/917bb4be17aab47a), after fixing the missing semicolon after the class. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In C++ classes default their member variables and methods to be private unless given the "public:" keyword. If you're trying to declare/initialize TheClass and use the doSomething method outside of the class you will need to make it accessible. Making it public is the simplest way to make the method accessible, but there are other ways. You are also missing a semicolon at the end of your class definition as mentioned in the comments. Everything else looks fine.

Here's a working example.

```html
#include <iostream>

class TheClass
{
  public:
    template<typename T>
    int doSomething(T thing);
};

template<typename T>
int TheClass::doSomething(T thing)
{
  std::cout << "doSomething(T thing)\n";
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  TheClass x;
  return x.doSomething(5);
}

Running the Program from console:
$ g++ class.c++ -o class
$ ./class

doSomething(T thing)
```